# Force user to exit dialog through buttons

Tags: android

I'm working on an app and at first startup I have two dialogs that I want the user to click ok/quit on(licensing, warnings etc) but currently they can be dismissed by clicking anywhere else on the screen.

I'm currently creating it like this;

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dlg.setTitle("Warning");
dlg.setMessage( ... );
dlg.setCancelable(false);
dlg.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { ... });
dlg.setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { ... });
dlg.create().show();
```

How do force the user to exit the dialog through one of the buttons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it. Changing it to

```
...snip...
builder.setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { ... });
AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
dlg.setCancelableOnTouchOutside(false);
dlg.show();
```